# No module named 'mediapipe.python._framework_bindings'

Tags: python, mediapipe

I installed Docker on raspberry PI 3b. I want to configure a Python image with Mediapipe.
The basic image is demosense/raspberrypi3-opencv.

The way I installed mediapipe is

```
apt-get update
apt update
apt-get update 
pip install mediapipe-rpi3 -i http://pypi.douban.com/simple --trusted-host pypi.douban.com
```

And then I realized that there was this mistake

```
root@ce01ec797bf6:/# python
Python 3.6.4 (default, Feb 13 2018, 04:59:47) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> import mediapipe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mediapipe/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from mediapipe.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mediapipe/python/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from mediapipe.python._framework_bindings import resource_util
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mediapipe.python._framework_bindings'
```